# SQLite select specific product and the rest ordered

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have an issue. Suppose i have the table in Northwind database, where there are orders placed containing some products.

```
Order | Product
1 | Milk
1 | Cacao
1 | Juice
2 | Milk
2 | LemonJuice
2 | OrangeJuice
3 | Lemonade
3 | Remoulade
3 | GrapefruitJuice
```

Suppose Order is being placed and it contains FX Order 1 Milk, Cacao, Juice. Order 2 has Milk, LemonJuice, OrangeJuice.
I need to select all the orders which contains Milk ordered and to select the rest what have they ordered, SO If person in order 1 has ordered Milk, then i need to take cacao and juice as well. The same in order 2, I see Milk ordered, then i need to take LemonJuice and OrangeJuice, Whereas Order 3 does not contain Milk, So I do not need it.
How can i do that? 
Trying for the second day, I am really in doubt of how to write it..

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: select customerID, ProductName, Quantity from Orders, Products INNER JOIN 'Order Details' ON Orders.OrderID = 'Order Details'.OrderID WHERE 'Order Details'.ProductID = Products.ProductID AND Products.ProductName = "Milk".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An embedded select would do it:

```
Select * from Orders where ord in
(select ord from Orders where Product = "Milk");
```

One thing I would like to point out is that "Order" is a keyword in SQLite, so you cannot name your column "Order". As you see in my code-snippet I renamed it to "ord". (The Table is called Orders and the second column is called (as in your description)  Product.

Comment: the solution given by you returns just all the Milks from the Orders, but i need ALL THE CONTENT, if there is a milk in order, then i need to return cacao and juice as well..

Comment: That should not be the case... The embedded select returns the Orders which contain  Milk. In you example this would be (1,2). The outer select returns Everything where the order is either 1 or 2... I suggest to test the two selects separately and then combine them! Also make sure you use the "in" keyword to connect them.